# Best antivirus for windows phone lumia 525

Tags: lumia

I looked on app store and not found any trustable popular antivirus..,
Why is there no antivirusd for windows phone ?

Answer (score 5):

Windows Phone do not need antivirus software. Apps run in a "sandbox" that prevents them from ripping your phone to shreds.